# How to grep recursive UNIX tree results along with each tree node?

Tags: files, find, executable

Here is what I do

```
tree -R /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0.app/ | perl -e 'while (<>) { print if /java$/ }'
```

but of course this doesn't return the result I want.

What I want is to display an **executable java file** along with its recursive directory so that I would know where that java file is. Something like this structure below

```
`-- Contents
    `-- Resources
        `-- NetBeans
            `-- ExecutableJavaEnv
                `-- java
```

[This question is inspired from my question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/314048/how-to-use-the-latest-java-from-netbeans-7-0-on-textmate). The structure display above actually is not really important because I'm not sure if I can get what I want using `find`. What I need is just **get the path** so that I can set my TextMate to run NetBeans' Java instead of `/usr/bin/java` from my Mac OS X 10.5.8. Advice? Help?

1st Edit:

Thanks for answers so far, I appreciate it. Here is the result of the command I tried:

```
. find /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0.app/ -name java
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.0.app//Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java
. ll /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/
total 632
-rw-rw-r--   1 arie  admin   6.6K Apr  8 09:29 CREDITS.html
-rw-rw-r--   1 arie  admin   1.7K Apr  8 09:29 DISTRIBUTION.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 arie  admin   2.1K Apr  8 09:30 LEGALNOTICE.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 arie  admin    78K Apr  8 09:30 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 arie  admin   5.4K Apr  8 09:30 README.html
-rw-rw-r--   1 arie  admin   158K Apr  8 09:30 THIRDPARTYLICENSE.txt
drwxrwxr-x   8 arie  admin   272B Apr  8 09:29 apisupport/
drwxrwxr-x   3 arie  admin   102B Apr  8 10:32 bin/
drwxrwxr-x   9 arie  admin   306B Jul  1 15:56 cnd/
drwxrwxr-x   9 arie  admin   306B Apr  8 09:29 dlight/
drwxrwxr-x   9 arie  admin   306B Apr  8 09:30 enterprise/
drwxrwxr-x   6 arie  admin   204B Apr  8 09:30 ergonomics/
drwxrwxr-x   6 arie  admin   204B Jun 11 22:17 etc/
drwxrwxr-x   7 arie  admin   238B Apr  8 09:30 groovy/
drwxrwxr-x  21 arie  admin   714B Jun 11 22:15 harness/
drwxrwxr-x  11 arie  admin   374B Jun 11 22:25 ide/
drwxrwxr-x  12 arie  admin   408B Jul  1 15:56 java/
drwxrwxr-x  10 arie  admin   340B Apr  8 10:15 mobility/
-rw-rw-r--   1 arie  admin    33K Apr  8 09:30 moduleCluster.properties
drwxrwxr-x  15 arie  admin   510B Jun 11 22:17 nb/
-rw-rw-r--   1 arie  admin    15K Apr  8 09:30 netbeans.css
drwxrwxr-x  11 arie  admin   374B Apr  8 09:30 php/
drwxrwxr-x  11 arie  admin   374B Jun 11 22:25 platform/
drwxrwxr-x  10 arie  admin   340B Apr  8 09:30 profiler/
drwxrwxr-x   3 arie  admin   102B Apr  8 08:43 ruby/
drwxrwxr-x   7 arie  admin   238B Apr  8 09:30 websvccommon/
.
```

And for another answer is this

```
. find /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0.app -type f -executable -name java
find: -executable: unknown option
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you looking for a file called `java` somewhere under a directory on your system? Are you looking for a file called `java` anywhere on your system? Are you trying to parse the output of `tree`, to extract only the parts that are the steps to a file called `java`? Something else?

Comment: @Gilles, Thanks for your response. Right, I'm looking for a file called `java` with its complete absolute path somewhere under `/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0.app` dir. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find executable files called `java` under the specified directory:

```
find '/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.0.app/' -name java -type f -perm -u+x
```

The output will be one file name per line, e.g.

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ExecutableJavaEnv/java
```

If you want to omit the `…/NetBeans 7.0.app` part, first switch to the directory and run `find` on the current directory (`.`). There'll still be a `./` prefix.

```
cd '/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.0.app/'
find . -name java -type f -perm -u+x
```

Strictly speaking, `-perm u+x` selects all files that are executable by their owner, not all files that you can execute. GNU find has a `-executable` option to look for files that you have execute permission on, taking all file modes and ACLs into account, but this option isn't available on other systems such as OSX. In practice, this is unlikely to matter; in fact for your use case you can forget about permissions altogether and just match `-name java -type f`.

`-type f` selects only regular files, not directories or symbolic links. If you want to include symbolic links to regular files in the search, add the `-L` option to `find` (immediately after the `find` command, before the name of the directory to search).

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted because the solution works for another case, ex. `find /opt/experiment/ruby/ -name ruby -type f -perm -u+x` gives me this `/opt/experiment/ruby//bin/ruby`. For java file I'm looking for in NB env [I updated my question on SU hopefully someone familiar with NetBeans and Java will come up](http://superuser.com/questions/314048/how-to-use-the-latest-java-from-netbeans-7-0-on-textmate). Thanks guys, all of you, wishing I could upvote, your answers all have been enlightening my day.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
find /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0.app -type f -executable -name java
```

Comment: yep, with type and executable checks it's better

Comment: @alex, why is it not working? :-/ `. find /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0.app -type f -executable -name java
find: -executable: unknown option` Should I change the options after find? But it's still error.

Comment: @ArieKeren `-executable` is specific to GNU find. In your case, just leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can be easily done with find: `find /path/ -name java`. (Why haven't you tried).

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't work. It gave me a dir called java, not a file.